# Click-through form on condition

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form which has various buttons and panels. I have one button which when pressed runs a check against some values and if the check passes I need the mouse click to fall through the form and hit whatever it is beneath the application window.

What I'm currently doing is after the button is pressed and the check has passed, I set the form to transparent using:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
private int oldWindowLong = 0;

public void SetFormTransparent(IntPtr Handle)
{
    oldWindowLong = GetWindowLong(Handle, -20);
    SetWindowLong(Handle, -20, Convert.ToInt32(oldWindowLong | 0x80000 | 0x20));
}

public void SetFormNormal(IntPtr Handle)
{
    SetWindowLong(Handle, -20, Convert.ToInt32(oldWindowLong | 0x80000));
}
```

Then I create a 1 millisecond timer, I simulate the mouse click using:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);
```

And set the form back to normal. This results in a really inconsistent and sometimes slow/unresponsive behavior.

What other options do I have if I want to simulate a mouse click as soon as the button's check has passed?

Comment: As long as the window has a parent, or is an owned window, then you can [use this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7692496/17034).

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the link, it was useful for me to know that. However my window is not owned by another one. It's the root one and I need the click to pass through it and hit other applications or the Desktop below it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is to use `Color.Magenta` as `TransparencyKey` and `BackColor` of your form.
Then make button invisible, and simulate a click event, then make the button visible again.

In this example, when you click on the button, it makes the form transparent and then simulates a click to pass through the form.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);

private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;

public void PerformClick()
{
    uint X = (uint)Cursor.Position.X;
    uint Y = (uint)Cursor.Position.Y;
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Just to keep the form on top
    this.TopMost = true;

    //Make form transparent and click through
    this.TransparencyKey = Color.Magenta;
    this.BackColor = Color.Magenta;

    //Make the button invisible and perform a click
    //The click reaches behind the button
    //Then make button visible again to be able handle clicks again
    this.button4.Visible = false;
    PerformClick();
    this.button4.Visible = true;
}
```

**Notes**

**Make Transparent and Click Through**
To make a form Transparent and make clicks pass through the form, you can simply Set the `TransparencyKey` property and `BackColor` property of your form to the same color `Color.Magenta`.

Pay attention that the key point is using Magenta as `TransparencyKey` and `BackColor`. For example, if you use Red, it makes the form transparent but doesn't make it click through.

If you have some controls on your form, they will remain visible and will receive clicks. If you need to make them invisible, you can simply set `Visible` property of them to `false`

**Make Normal**
To make that form normal, it's enough to set `BackColor` to another color different than `TransparencyKey`, for example `SystemColors.Control`

Comment: Thank you. I have already used a TransparencyKey with another color to make the form transparent but this does not make my clicks fall through the window. Performing clicks on buttons does not simulate a click beneath the application window so I can't use that either.

Comment: The key point is in using Magenta as color, for example Red makes your form transparent but not pass through but Magenta makes it both transparent and click pass through.

Comment: @Footch Let me know if you checked the solution:)

Comment: Yes, I tried it and you are right, Magenta does make the form click-through but it doesn't apply to the button (I don't need the button to be transparent, only click-through if conditions are met). What I need is when I click the button the click to fall through the button, the form and the whole window allowing me to click whatever it is beneath the application's window.

Comment: @Footch Check the ultimate solution :)

Comment: You point out that the color needs to be Magenta, furthermore, @Footch mentions it doesn't work with other colors. Maybe you could expand your answer to include an explanation?

Comment: @kres0345 it's an old bug/issue. The trick works for some colors, for example if you use Color.Red it will be transparent but handles clicks, but using Magenta the form will be mouse transparent too.

Comment: @RezaAghaei oh okay, sounds like a clever work-around, thanks

Comment: I tested for a few colors and apparently the R and the B has to be the same in RGB colors, in order for you to click through the form.